# C# Reading a text file provided via the command line in the way of StandardInput

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, file, fizzbuzz

I am trying to figure out the old FizzBuzz challenge. I figured out the logic behind the FizzBuzz part (printing Fizz for numbers divisible by 3, Buzz for numbers divisible by 5, and FizzBuzz for numbers divisible by both).

**Instructions:**

Players generally sit in a circle. The first player says the number “1”, and each player says next number in turn. However, any number divisible by X (for example, three) is replaced by the word fizz, and any divisible by Y (for example, five) by the word buzz. Numbers divisible by both become fizz buzz. A player who hesitates, or makes a mistake is eliminated from the game.
Write a program that prints out the final series of numbers where those divisible by X, Y and both are replaced by “F” for fizz, “B” for buzz and “FB” for fizz buzz.

INPUT SAMPLE:
Your program should accept a file as its first argument. The file contains multiple separated lines; each line contains 3 numbers that are space delimited. The first number is the first divider (X), the second number is the second divider (Y), and the third number is how far you should count (N). You may assume that the input file is formatted correctly and the numbers are valid positive integers.

For example:
3 5 10
2 7 15

OUTPUT SAMPLE:
Print out the series 1 through N replacing numbers divisible by X with “F”, numbers divisible by Y with “B” and numbers divisible by both with “FB”. Since the input file contains multiple sets of values, your output should print out one line per set. Ensure that there are no trailing empty spaces in each line you print.

1 2 F 4 B F 7 8 F B
1 F 3 F 5 F B F 9 F 11 F 13 FB 15

CONSTRAINTS:

•   The number of test cases ≤ 20

•   "X" is in range [1, 20]

•   "Y" is in range [1, 20]

•   "N" is in range [21, 100]

I am not looking for someone to do this for me, just help me better understand how I am to read the text file. My apologies if this is a "dumb" question. I have researched Microsoft's Development Network page for clarification but that just confused me even more.... Thank you.

Comment: From the instructions, it sounds like your program shouldn't read from StandardInput. It should read a command line argument in order to get a filename, and then it should open and read that file.

Comment: @TannerSwett that is what I thought as well. I was provided with additional instructions... // The input will be a text file provided via the command line in the way of StandardInput
            //You'll need to implement Parse input and send the results to StandardOutput
            //Use whatever object structure you would like to use, the ParseInput return types are changeable.

Comment: The question is too broad, you should split it into: "how to read from stdin" and "how to solve the FizzBuzz" or the next problem you encounter after reading from stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard output (**stdout**) is just the regular console output;

to send something to it, just do `Console.WriteLine`.

to send to **stderr** `Console.Error.WriteLine`, but it's not required by the challange.

The challange on **CodeEval** doesn't require you to input anything from the **stdin**, you just take the file name from the first argument of your **Main** method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileContent = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
}
```

If you have to read effectively from the **stdin**, you could just use `Console.ReadLine`:

```
string line;

while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Do whatever you need to do with the line variable read from the stdin.
}
```

or integrating with the code you provided:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(FizzBuzz.ParseInput(reader));
}
```

And, yet another option if you just need to parse text: `Console.In`

Comment: Thank you for your response! It is beginning to make more sense. I was provided with some code for main, which was `using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new    System.IO.StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput()))` in addition to this method:  `public static object ParseInput(string fileName)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader input = System.IO.File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                return FizzBuzz.ParseInput(input);
            }
        }`

Comment: `Console.OpenStandardInput` gives you a `Stream` to read from the **stdin**, if you are doing the challange on **CodeEval** I think the input is provided as an argument, this can be confirmed if you use the web editor they provide instead of uploading your solution; their boilerplate code I think uses `new FileStream(args[0])`, I'll double check.

Comment: Confirmed, the online editor you have when you try to submit uses: `using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(args[0]))`. If it's a different site might be using the **stdin** instead; in that case you can use your example or my last one.

Comment: Yeah this one is not for CodeEval. I will play around with it. I believe I do need to use the **stdin**. Thanks!

Comment: I am still a bit lost as to how I am opening this file. I am sorry, I'm still learning many concepts. I updated my original post with the my code. As I mentioned, some of it was provided with the challenge.

Comment: If the challenge site gives you the output of your program you should simply read the input and print it so you can see what's going on and focus on the next problem; I see few problems with your code, but they are not related to the original question.

Comment: If they don't give you output, you should try do it yourself locally anyway and debug it, it's easy to send stdin to a console application.